# Not call the HelpRequest function

Tags: sapui5

I have a `Input field` created into a **controller**.

```
sap.ui.getCore().byId("SimpleFormChange354").addContent(new sap.m.Input({value : "", enabled:true, editable:true, showValueHelp:true, valueHelpOnly:true, valueHelpRequest:"handleValueHelp"}));
```

In the same `controller` I define the function:

```
handleValueHelp : function (oCOntroller) {
        if (! this._oDialog) {
          this._oDialog = sap.ui.xmlfragment("apps.appIntra.fragment.dialogClienti", this);
        }

        .....
  },
```

But if i click on the suggestion element at the end of `input field` i have an **error**:

```
Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function sap-ui-core.js:122
a.fireEvent sap-ui-core.js:122
a.fireEvent sap-ui-core.js:134
(anonymous function) sap-ui-core.js:134
sap.m.Input._fireValueHelpRequestForValueHelpOnly Input.js:16
sap.m.Input.ontap Input.js:17
a._callEventHandles sap-ui-core.js:134
a._handleEvent sap-ui-core.js:134
U._handleEvent sap-ui-core.js:134
Q.extend.proxy.p sap-ui-core.js:16
Q.event.dispatch sap-ui-core.js:27
g jquery-mobile-custom.js:17
p jquery-mobile-custom.js:17
Q.event.dispatch sap-ui-core.js:27
Q.event.add.v3.handle sap-ui-core.js:27
Q.event.trigger sap-ui-core.js:27
(anonymous function) sap-ui-core.js:27
Q.extend.each sap-ui-core.js:16
Q.fn.Q.each sap-ui-core.js:16
Q.fn.extend.trigger sap-ui-core.js:27
P jquery-mobile-custom.js:17
R jquery-mobile-custom.js:17
Q.event.dispatch sap-ui-core.js:27
Q.event.add.v3.handle sap-ui-core.js:27
```

Instead, if I try to attach the function by:

```
sap.ui.getCore().byId("SimpleFormChange354").addContent(new sap.m.Input({value : "", enabled:true, editable:true, showValueHelp:true, valueHelpOnly:true}).attachValueHelpRequest(this.handleValueHelp(this)));
```

when in execution time I arrive at this code the `handleValueHelp` get fired  (immediately, not even I click on suggestion item!).

Then, I try to click on the suggestion item i got this error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'call' of undefined sap-ui-core.js:122
a.fireEvent sap-ui-core.js:122
a.fireEvent sap-ui-core.js:134
(anonymous function) sap-ui-core.js:134
sap.m.Input._fireValueHelpRequestForValueHelpOnly Input.js:16
sap.m.Input.ontap Input.js:17
a._callEventHandles sap-ui-core.js:134
a._handleEvent sap-ui-core.js:134
U._handleEvent sap-ui-core.js:134
Q.extend.proxy.p sap-ui-core.js:16
Q.event.dispatch sap-ui-core.js:27
g jquery-mobile-custom.js:17
p jquery-mobile-custom.js:17
Q.event.dispatch sap-ui-core.js:27
Q.event.add.v3.handle sap-ui-core.js:27
Q.event.trigger sap-ui-core.js:27
(anonymous function) sap-ui-core.js:27
Q.extend.each sap-ui-core.js:16
Q.fn.Q.each sap-ui-core.js:16
Q.fn.extend.trigger sap-ui-core.js:27
P jquery-mobile-custom.js:17
R jquery-mobile-custom.js:17
Q.event.dispatch sap-ui-core.js:27
Q.event.add.v3.handle
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your first line you have:

```
valueHelpRequest:"handleValueHelp"}));
```

which is just a string.
Replace that string with the actual reference to your method:

```
valueHelpRequest:this.handleValueHelp}));
```

and it will work ;-)

Comment: thank you! It work! But... why if I use the .attachValueHelpRequest(this.handleValueHelp())
I have an error?

Comment: Due to the braces at `handleValueHelp()` you execute the function rather then passing it as parameter. So only `this.handleValueHelp` is the way to pass the function as parameter.